# PWM output always 0 on proteus (using atmega328p and assembly on microchip studio to write the code)

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega, pwm, proteus

i am currently trying to setup a servo motor on a proteus circuit using a PWM signal (TCR0) on the atmega328p , i went through several manual books to setup the bits in the TCCR0A and TCCR0B registers and the duty cycle value on OCR0A and expect an output on the OCR0A port.

```
.INCLUDE "M328PDEF.INC"
.ORG 0x00

 SBI DDRD , 6 // port D6 output for PWM 
 
 LOOP:
 CALL TESTN
 CALL delay
 JMP LOOP
TESTN:  
    LDI R20 , 127 //duty cycle value (50%)
    STS OCR0A , R20 // duty cycle on OCR0A
    LDI R17 , 0b10000011
    STS TCCR0A , R17 //Non-Inverting Fast PWM mode 3 using OCRA 
    LDI R18 , 0b00000001
    STS TCCR0B , R18 //No-Prescalar
    //LDS R20 , OCR0A // trying to output on port D6 but maybe doesnt matter
    //OUT PORTD , R20
    

delay:
    LDI R16 , 1
        L0: LDI R17 , 1
            L1: LDI R18 , 20
                L2: DEC R18
                    BRNE L2
                    DEC R17
                    BRNE L1
                    DEC R16
                    BRNE L0
                    RET
```

[proteus circuit results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNunO.png)

Can anyone tell me what i am missing ?
Any help is appreciated ,thanks in advance

I expected to receive a signal on portD,6 which will result in a movement of the servo but the output is always 0 on that port (not sure why other ports have output values without actually defining anything regarding them)
Edit : if anyone knows a good compiler from C to avr assembly it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler if you write the code in C and then look at the disassembly.

Note: Timer0 registers (`TCCR0A`, `TCCR0B`, `OCR0A` etc) are in the lower range of I/O-registers and can be accessed both by memory access operations (like `STS`, `LDS`) using their memory address, and also can be accessed by `IN` and `OUT` operations, using their I/O-register number.

How your constant are declared? For example, if `TCCR0A` equals to *0x44*, then it is a memory address, and `STS` should be used. But if it equals to *0x24* then it is IO-register number and `OUT` should be used instead.

Also, there is no `ret` at the end of `TESTN` in your code

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply,i filled the TCCRO registers according to the following documents: [link](https://www.ee-diary.com/2021/07/atmega328p-fast-pwm-mode-programming.html#) so the resulting C code is: `int main()
 {     DDRD |= (1<<PD6);    //Fast PWM output at OC0A pin
   OCR0A = 191;// Duty cycle of 75%
 TCCR0A |= (1<<COM0A1) | (1<<WGM01) | (1<<WGM00); //Non-Inverting Fast PWM mode 3 using OCR A unit
 TCCR0B |= (1<<CS00); //No-Prescalar
   while (1);
   return 0; }`  after using OUT instead of STS the servo is now spinning just in the -180 degrees and is stuck there

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i needed prescaling since the atmega32p has 18MHz processor speed which wont provide the 20ms duration signal needed by a servo motor. I used 8 prescaling (TCCR0B = 0b00000100) and adjust the angle through the OCR0A values.